# When I run python code in vs code I get this error: zsh: command not found: python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using mac os but, from 4 months ago there was an update for Mac, and I was working in vscode normally with Python, but when the update finished downloading, vscode never worked with any Python code, but the rest of the languages ​​were working normally, I tried a lot but i didnt get anything so i downloaded pycharm but i like vscode can anyone help me.

my input :

```
print("Hello, World")
```

output :

```
zsh: command not found: python
```

my python version :

```
name@name ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.10.7
name@name ~ %
```

Comment: It looks like your python executable is named `python3`, not `python`. Did you try setting the interpreter in VSCode?

Comment: Also, have you tried adding a shebang at the very top of the code? Try this if not: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

There is python3 on your machine, but the `python` command of the mac system points to python2 by default. You need to use the following command to point `python` to python3.

```
echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Aliases are not honored by noninteractive shells. The problem is diagnosed correctly, but the proposed solution is not a good one.